# SOLVED: why does my windows 10 user path show fully duplicated values from system path?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, path

My windows 10 user path variable only has the entry `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`
I have put all other path settings into the system path variable.
If I open a command prompt and echo %path%, the result is "all of the entries from my system path" plus "my user path" plus "again my system path " plus an obscure "C:\PROGRA~2\FLASHM~1" at the end.
If I open an administrative command prompt and echo %path%, the path is properly plain as set in the environment variables applet.
If I remove my user path variable completely the user path is still duplicated from the system path and also has the C:PROGRA~2\FLASHM~1 appendix.
The latter is the short name for C:\Program Files (x86)\Flash Magic.

Does anybody know what process creates the user path?

I did a registry search on the path settings but could not find anything helpful.
There was also no hints about the FlashMagic entry.
I suppose there is some service or scheduled task or startup process which modifies the PATH variable, but I did not succeed to find it.

Addon:
FlashMagic is a tool from NXP Semiconductors for its microcontrollers.
I have uploaded the zipped archive tree to my dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/dun2zm69erugxir/flashmagicTree.zip?dl=0

Comment: What are the contents of the application directory for Flash Magic?  You can [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the installation of FlashMagic has created a C:\Autoexec.bat file which did the PATH modification.
It seems that this mechanism from the days of legacy windows still exists.
Even autoruns.exe from sysinternals did not show this startup ramp.